# I can't randomly distribute the contents of a collection in Blender 3.0 geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

In 2.93 I can easily randomly distribute the contents of a collection within a geometry nodes graph.
In 3.0 how would I now achieve the same result? I've attached an image from both 2.93 and 3.0 to illustrate the issue. [image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this because although it is still under development. This is basic functionality and it works in 3.0...I don't understand why this must not be answered or questioned although it is Blender and other questions even about other software are allowed and won't be deleted or closed. It is just not fair. Sorry, Gavin, i really like to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Gavin, you can use this node setup - it works: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6vYY.png

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because Blender 3.0 is stable now and it's the first result for this type of thing on a search.

Comment: @deltaray: did you read my comment?